# Laravel Eloquent how to get all products according to category id

Tags: php, laravel, e-commerce

**UserProductsController**

```
class UserProductsController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $products = Product::get();
        return view ('products')->with(compact('products'));
      
    }
      
    public function product_categories()
    {
        $categories = Category::all();
        return view ('categories')->with(compact('categories'));
      
    }
  
}
```

**products_table**

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('prod_name');
            $table->string('prod_brand')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('cat_id');
            $table->string('prod_image_path')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('cat_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('categories')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }
```

**categories_table**

```
   public function up()
        {
            Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->bigIncrements('id');
                $table->string('cat_name');
                $table->string('cat_image_path')->nullable();
                $table->string('cat_description')->nullable();
                $table->timestamps();
            });
        }
```

**Product** Model

```
class Product extends Model
{
  

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category','category_id');
    }
 
    
}
```

**Category** Model

```
class Category extends Model
{
   public function category()
   {
       return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
   }
}
```

My route is

```
Route::get('/All_Products', 'UserProductsController@index')->name('All_Products');
Route::get('/product_categories', 'UserProductsController@product_categories')->name('categories');
```

How can I get all products with the same category? As this is my first project I am spending much more time on this. But nothing worked for me. Can anyone guide me, please?

Comment: Not related to your question, but the `category()`  relationship method on your Product model is incorrect, it should be `$this->belongsTo('App\Category', 'cat_id')` because your column with the foreign key is called `cat_id` and not `category_id`

Answer (score 2):

**Assuming you setup your relationships correctly (which they are not)**

You have a few ways with Eloquent:

```
$products = Category::findOrFail($categoryId)->products;

$products = Product::where('category_id', $categoryId)->get();

$products = Product::whereHas('category', function ($query) use ($categoryId) {
    $q->where('id', $categoryId);
})->get();
```

To list a few.

[Laravel 7.x Docs - Eloquent - Retrieving Single Models / Aggregates](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#retrieving-single-models) `findOrFail`

[Laravel 7.x Docs - Eloquent - Relationships - Relationship Methods vs Dynamic Properties](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#relationship-methods-vs-dynamic-properties)

[Laravel 7.x Docs - Eloquent - Relationships - Querying the Existence of Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) `whereHas`

Comment: These are all solid choices. The first option should be your go to if you already have a category model available. The second option is great if you don't need access to any of the properties of the Category model (no table joins required). The third option would be a less common way of doing it, but it will 100% work.

Comment: While these options all work in theory, to make it work in OP's case the second option should be `cat_id` instead of `category_id` and the third option won't work since the relationship is setup incorrectly, again because of `category_id` => `cat_id`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have not defined your relationships correctly. It should be something like this:

```php
class Product extends Model
{
    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
    }
}
```

```php
class Category extends Model
{
   public function products()
   {
       return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
   }
}
```

Then in your products migration file, `cat_id` should be renamed to `category_id`. That way, you don't need to specify the foreign key on the relationship.

I assume you want to list all the products that belong to a particular category. You can easily do that with the route model binding. In which case your route should look something like:

```php
Route::get('categories/{category:id}/products', [CategoryController::class, 'products']);
```

And then in your controller:

```php
use App\Category;

class CategoryController extends Controller
{
    public function products(Category $category)
    {
        $category->load('products');

        return view('products')->withCategory($category);
    } 
}
```

You can access the list of products in your blade view like so: `$category->products`

Comment: I add href in blade. <a href="{{route('categorize',$c->category_id)}}">. It throws error as Missing required parameters for [Route: categorize] [URI: categorize/{category_id}].

Comment: `$c->category_id` should be `$c->id` I think.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make an adjustment to your `Category` model as a `Category` has many `Products`. As it stands, the naming of the relationship doesn't reflect that

```
class Category extends Model
{
   public function products()
   {
       return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
   }
}
```

You can then access the products via the `Category` model like so.

```
$categories = Category::with('products')->all();

$categories->each(function($category) {
    $products = $category->products;
    
    // Dump & Die a collection of products
    dd($products);
});
```

*Note:* I have eager loaded the relationship using the `with()` method, this is just to prevent `n+1` queries. More information on eager and lazy loading can be found on the documentation.

Comment: it's incorrectly named. It should be `products` and not `category`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like,

```
$products = product::with('categories')->get();
foreach($products as $product)
{
    foreach($product->categories as $category)
    {
        echo $category->name;
    }
}
$categories = Category::with('products')->get();

$category = Category::with('products')->find($category_id);
```